# Text on the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys I have a problem with the records in this page:
There's a big empty space between the text and the bottom of the page

It should be:
[Correct Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f7Yv.png)
But is: 
[Wrong Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZlCt.jpg)
This is the code of the record, it's a lineat layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="daxilgames.footballplayersquiz2018.Pagina1">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record: 0 punti"
            android:id="@+id/record"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:id="@+id/recordn"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record Nazionali: 0 punti"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are going to want to use layout gravity property on the View that is loading the above layout

Comment: You mean: <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Record: 0 punti">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Record Nazionali: 0 punti"/>             I have already tried it

Comment: No. that linear layout is being loaded into another view, which needs the gravity property. If you put it on the text view and its already filling the whole space of parent it wont do anything.

You should add a background colour property to see which view the space belongs to at the bottom that needs filled. Then change the gravity on that view

Answer (score 0):

You use `ConstraintLayout`, so you can use constraints to set positions of textViews in the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Record: 0 punti"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recordn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Record Nazionali: 0 punti"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't works on my Oneplus 5t :( , it center only the text

Answer (score 0):

If your parent layout is a `LinearLayout` you can just add `android:gravity="bottom"` to it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record: 0 punti"
        android:id="@+id/record"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:id="@+id/recordn"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record Nazionali: 0 punti"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's correct but now there is a big empty space between the logo and the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
tools:context="daxilgames.footballplayersquiz2018.Pagina1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record: 0 punti"
        android:id="@+id/record"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:id="@+id/recordn"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Record Nazionali: 0 punti"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Change your root opening tag to `LinearLayout` and add this property `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Comment: No that's not this the problem (i've cut a part of my code because stackoverflow doesn't make me create the thread, excuse me for haven't explained that before)

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved :D
I've created two layouts, one Linear layout with gravity top, the second for the two strings with gravity bottom`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record: 0 punti"
            android:id="@+id/record"/>

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:id="@+id/recordn"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="113dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record Nazionali: 0 punti"/>`
```